# Configure sendmail to send only

Tags: configuration, sendmail

I want to configure sendmail only to send emails – not to listen and receive. In <kbd>/etc/mail/sendmail.conf</kbd> I’ve got:

```
DAEMON_MODE="None";
QUEUE_MODE="Daemon";
```

Iptables are disabled (temporarily; only for this test)

But in <kbd>/var/log/mail/mail.log</kbd>

```
Nov 18 13:40:04 novy sm-msp-queue[13548]: rAIC9RiF012445: to=user@mydomain.com, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:30:37, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=390130, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]
```

When I set in <kbd>/etc/mail/sendmail.conf</kbd> `DAEMON_MODE="Daemon";` e-mails are successfully sent.

Is that needed – to listen?

Comment: How do you expect to send mail if you disable the daemon, but also set the queue mode to "daemon"?

Comment: /etc/mail/sendmail.conf is specific to your OS/distro. In fact, nothing like this is standard.

Answer (score 0):

This applies if you really are running `sendmail`, not something that pretends to be an "alternative" sendmail.

The way a default `sendmail` installation usually works is:

- an MTA daemon listening on (at least) localhost:25
- a non-listening MSP queue-running daemon that sends from the clientmqueue to that MTA

In each case there's a spool directory, `/var/spool/mqueue` and `/var/spool/clientmqueue` respectively. These have different permissions, originally to  solve problems with setuid-root binaries, local mail submission requires setgid "smmsp" to write to the clientmqueue spool.

When you send an email e.g. using sendmail (or mailx) it uses  a "client" mode that if it cannot connect to localhost it just adds to the clientmqueue (or you can force queueing with `-ODeliveryMode=q`) from where the queue-runner will retry it periodically.

The important thing to note is that there's always a sendmail listening because the submit process tries to do as little as practical with as few permissions as practical. Your error log above is that submit process failing to connect to the MTA daemon (because you turned it off).

Simple options are

1. make sure your listening daemon is 127.0.0.1 (and/or ::1) only via

   ```
   DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp,Addr=127.0.0.1,Name=SUBMIT')
   ```

   in the `sendmail.mc` file, then it can only receive from itself (although this is not wildly different from using iptables to block inbound SMTP).   This is only a solution if you mean "not to listen and receive *from the network*".
2. change the "submit" default of connecting to 127.0.0.1 with

   ```
   FEATURE(`msp', `[127.0.0.1]')
   ```

   and replace 127.0.0.1 with your "smarthost" or local SMTP relay

To make either of the above changes this you'll should have the sendmail cf/m4 support files installed, which may be an extra package. Add/amend the
directives indicated in the source .mc files (usually `sendmail.mc` and `submit.mc`) and run the provided make script to rebuild the `sendmail.cf` and/or `submit.cf` files.

You will find brave souls who modify their `.cf` files directly to effect the above, I don't recommend that approach...

Comment: @ChrisDavies good catch, fixed! (I have actually used multiple 127.0.0.x addresses on loopback to enable multiple distinct sendmail instances, e.g. inbound and outbound with MIMEDefang)